# Обновление содержимого в QGroupBox по клику кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea, qgroupbox, qvboxlayout

Столкнулся с проблемой того, что не могу обновить содержимое внутри `QGroupBox`. 
Я хочу получать все картинки из стандартной папки *Pictures в Windows* и по нажатию кнопки, если картинок стало больше или меньше обновлять это во `view`, но при запуске `updater` функция `showImg` получает список с новыми изображениями и складывает их внутрь списка `pix_dict`, но не перерисовывает виджет.

Вот минимально воспроизводимый пример на PyQT5:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QScrollArea, QPushButton
from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.update_photo(), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.test_widget_2(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(grid)


    def update_photo(self):
        but = QPushButton('Обновить')
        but.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        but.clicked.connect(self.updater)
        return but

    def test_widget_2(self):
        but = QPushButton('test_but_2')
        but.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        return but

    def updater(self):
        self.showImg().close()
        self.showImg()

    def find(self, pattern, path):
        result = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for name in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                    result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        return result

    def showImg(self):
        path = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shellcon.FOLDERID_Pictures)

        all_image = self.find('*.jpg', f'{path}')
        pix_dict = []
        for image in all_image:
            pxm = QPixmap(image)
            pix_dict.append(pxm)

        box = QGroupBox()
        box.setStyleSheet("border:0;")

        scr = QScrollArea(self)
        scr.setStyleSheet('height:0px; width:0px;')
        pnl = QWidget(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for image in list(reversed(pix_dict)):
            photo_label = QLabel()
            photo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            photo_label.setMaximumSize(200, 120)
            photo_label.setPixmap(image.scaled(photo_label.width(), photo_label.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

            vbox.addWidget(photo_label)

        pnl.setLayout(vbox)
        scr.setWidget(pnl)
        scr.setWidgetResizable(True)

        group_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        group_box_layout.addWidget(scr)
        box.setLayout(group_box_layout)
        return box

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Предлагаю вам использовать [QListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) в режиме `QListView::IconMode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, \
    QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QScrollArea, QPushButton
    
#from win32comext.shell import shell, shellcon


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.box = QGroupBox()
        self.box.setStyleSheet("border: 0;")
        self.group_box_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.box)
 
        self.scr = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scr.setStyleSheet('height: 0px; width: 0px;') 
        self.scr.setWidgetResizable(True)
       
        self.showImg()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
        
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.update_photo(), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        
#        grid.addWidget(self.showImg(), 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.box, 1, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)                 # +++ self.box
        
        grid.addWidget(self.test_widget_2(), 2, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def update_photo(self):
        but = QPushButton('Обновить')
        but.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        but.clicked.connect(self.updater)
        return but

    def test_widget_2(self):
        but = QPushButton('test_but_2')
        but.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        return but

    def updater(self):
#        self.showImg().close()
        self.showImg()

    def find(self, pattern, path):
        result = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for name in files:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                    result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        return result

    def showImg(self):
#       path = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shellcon.FOLDERID_Pictures)
# +++           v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^
        path = 'D:/_Qt/__Qt/Test/testtest/test'                  # установите свой путь

        all_image = self.find('*.jpg', f'{path}')
        pix_dict = []
        for image in all_image:
            pxm = QPixmap(image)
            pix_dict.append(pxm)

#        box = QGroupBox()
#        self.box.setStyleSheet("border: 0;")
#        scr = QScrollArea(self)
#        scr.setStyleSheet('height: 0px; width: 0px;')
        pnl = QWidget() # self

#        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(pnl)                                        # !!! +++ 
        
        for image in list(reversed(pix_dict)):
            photo_label = QLabel()
            photo_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            photo_label.setMaximumSize(200, 120)             
            photo_label.setPixmap(
                image.scaled(photo_label.width(), 
                photo_label.height(), 
                Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

            vbox.addWidget(photo_label)

#        pnl.setLayout(vbox)
        self.scr.setWidget(pnl)
#        scr.setWidgetResizable(True)
        
#                                      
#        group_box_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.box)
        self.group_box_layout.addWidget(self.scr)                     # !!! +++ 
        
#        box.setLayout(group_box_layout)
#        return box


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]